# Create alarms in Android

Tags: android, android-alarms

i used below code to create alarm.

```
public static void RegisterForAlarmEvent(Context ct, long intervel)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ct, AlarmReceiver.class);

            PendingIntent mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ct,
                    constants.ALARM_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ct
                    .getSystemService(ct.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Long totalTime = getCurrentTimeinMiliSeconds() + intervel;

            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, totalTime , mAlarmSender);
        }
```

I need to check next time, if the alarm is already registered & its triggered. If its triggered then only i need to re-register.

So, i'm checking like this to know, if the alaram is already registered.

```
boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ct, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE)!= null);
```

If i call register using alaramevent method & check alarm is already registered i get NULL, literally it should return NULL, once the alarm is executed right?

How to check alarm is already fired or not?

Answer (score 0):

According to docs **FLAG_NO_CREATE**:

```
Flag for use with getActivity, getBroadcast, and getService: if the described PendingIntent does not already exist, then simply return null instead of creating it.
```

So if the pending intent already created then it will return the reference to the previous pending intent. If not then it will return null.

And the answer to your question is maintain some shared preference value and change that value in broadcast receiver. Based on that value

Comment: Even i was also thinking the same, i'll try... thanks